# Equality of pdfs when there is a one-to-one relation between them

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the book Monte Carlo Methods for Particle Transport, and I came across the following statements (paraphrased):

Given two random variables $\eta \in [0,1]$, $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$, want to find a random number generator with a uniform pdf,

$$
q(\eta) = 1, \space \space \space \space 0 \leq \eta \leq 1
$$

If $\eta = \frac{\phi}{2\pi}$, because there is a one-to-one relation between $\eta$ and $\phi$, and assuming we know $p(\phi)$, we can obtain a pdf for $\eta$ using the following equality:

$$
|q(\eta)d\eta| = |p(\phi)d\phi|
$$
so that,
$$
q(\eta) = p(\phi)\Bigg|\frac{d\phi}{d\eta}\Bigg| = p(\phi)(2\pi)
$$

because $p(\phi)$ and $q(\eta)$ are positive.

My questions are:

1. Why is the equality with the absolute values true?
2. Under what conditions does it hold - i.e. is it true for all functions with a one-to-one relation or only for pdfs?
3. What is the meaning of the absolute value of a differential (e.g. $|d\phi|$) in this context?

Comment: I would ignore $|q(\eta)d\eta| = |p(\phi)d\phi|$ The main point is the line below it, which is the change of variables theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability

Comment: If $\eta=\frac\phi{2\pi}$ then $\frac{d \phi}{d \eta}={2\pi}$.  If $\eta=1-\frac\phi{2\pi}$ then $\frac{d \phi}{d \eta}=-{2\pi}$. But in both cases you want to rescale the density by a positive factor (densities cannot be negative), which is why you need the absolute value of the derivative